# How to check if the span element by name has a tag with class higlight using cypress and react?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

i am new to programming and learning cypress with react and typescript. i have html like below,

```
<li>
    <a class="StyledListItemContent-sc-wfozlt-l jqmJwr highlight hover link"> 
        //should check if this <a> tag has class "highlight"
        <div class="Box-sc fzjcGf"></div>
        <div class="Box-sc Flex-sc-1pzo701-0">
            <span>some type (some type) </span> //using this span name some type 
            <span style="display">...</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

how can i check if the span element with name "some type" has `<a>` tag with class "highlight" using cypress.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what do you mean by "has a tag"? `<span>` is already a tag.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. <a > tag i mean. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The span might be accessed with `cy.contains()` since you are looking for some text in it.

The `<a>` is a parent but it's two levels above, so `cy.parents('a')` should find it.

Then the attribute can be asserted.

```js
cy.contains('span', 'some type')
  .parents('a')
  .should('have.class', 'highlight')
```

Comment: thanks this works except that i had to use class instead of attr like .should('have.class', 'highlight')

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thanks for pointing that out.